# (emacs) Inserting line break into a rectangle

Tags: emacs

When replacing rectangle contents with a string, I don't seem to be able to insert a newline onto it.

I've tried pressing 'Enter', which just finishes the string edit and replaces it for the rectangle contents.

And I've also tried 'Ctrl + q', for quoted insertion, then typing 'Enter', but emacs types in a '^M'.

My problem:

```html
<img id="img1" src="images/img1.jpg">
<img id="img2" src="images/img1.jpg">
<img id="img3" src="images/img1.jpg">
```

I want to add a property into all these lines simultaneously, like this:

```html
<img id="img1" onclick="load_another_image()" src="images/img1.jpg">
<img id="img2" onclick="load_another_image()" src="images/img1.jpg">
<img id="img3" onclick="load_another_image()" src="images/img1.jpg">
```

Then I want to insert a newline after the newly placed function so the line doesn't get too big:

```html
<img id="img1" onclick="load_another_image()"
src="images/img1.jpg">
<img id="img2" onclick="load_another_image()"
src="images/img1.jpg">
<img id="img3" onclick="load_another_image()"
src="images/img1.jpg">
```

I've also found this [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28837/inserting-line-break-into-a-rectangle), but it doesn't quite answer the question.

So, how can i add a newline char into a string to replace rectangle contents in emacs?

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you are asking. Please show what you have tried (using a rectangle), step by step. It's not clear where you are inserting newline chars in your example - the desired result seems to have the same lines as the original - no additional newline chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried pressing 'Enter', which just finishes the string edit and replaces it for the rectangle contents.
>
> And I've also tried 'Ctrl + q', for quoted insertion, then typing 'Enter', but emacs types in a '^M'.
>
> [...]
>
> So, how can i add a newline char into a string to replace rectangle contents in emacs?

You were very close to the solution.

The newline character is not `^M` but `^J`.

That is, instead of typing <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> (which for historical reasons is the same as <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-m</kbd>) you wanted:

<kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>

That is the way to insert a newline in any situation when <kbd>RET</kbd> does something different. (For another example, see the Q&A that you found and linked to.)

This seems to work reliably with `string-rectangle`, and you could use it with the `multiple-cursors` library as well.

With `cua-set-rectangle-mark` I'm uncertain -- It *can* work there, because when I first tested a few minutes ago it worked; but I've also seen it only insert a newline at one of the positions, so either it's unreliable, or I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 3):

hopefully I have not misunderstood your goal.  But, here goes:

1) move your cursor to the top of where you want to insert text:
[image]

2) set the mark (for me its <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>) at the top

3) move the cursor to the bottom of the area:
[image]

4) now we need to run the command (<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> string-rectangle)
 for me its mapped to the keyboard short cut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>

5) then you start typing your text, you should see it live edit in the rectangle.  when you are happy you hit enter:
[image]

hope this helps.  If you want to do a new line ('\n') then you should use a call to query replace regex with a capture pattern (I can explain more if you want that)

Comment: n.b. You can type `C-q C-j` to insert a newline at all positions.

Comment: Thanks phils, that was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are two rectangle implementations included with Emacs, the one in `cua-rect.el` and the one in `rect.el`.  I like `cua-rect` better.  Note that `cua-rect` is independent of `cua-mode`.

Do `M-x cua-rectangle-mark-mode` (I bind this to `C-RET`), notice that there's some help in the minibuffer before you start moving (though you probably don't need it for this task), extend your rectangle with arrows, type some text.  The text will be inserted on every line in the rectangle, and will be inserted in the column the cursor is on.

Comment: n.b. You can type `C-q C-j` to insert a newline at all positions.

Comment: Ooh. Maybe. I suddenly can't reproduce that behaviour, but I could before -- so it's definitely possible, but I'm also missing something...

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see the newline part of the question, and it seems like `cua-rect` doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me where you are trying to insert newlines in your example.

I will say that if you use [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el), you can insert newline characters with <kbd>C-j</kbd> by default.  If you want <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a newline, you can use `(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<return>") nil)` in your config.